# multiple variables in a bash loop

Tags: bash, svn

I am writing a shell script that gets me the status of a directory in svn then loops through it and either adds or deletes the files.

This svn command

```
$ svn status /myLocalDir/files
```

returns files i have either added or deleted locally. ? = add, ! = deleted

```
!        /myLocalDir/files/deletedPicture.png
?        /myLocalDir/files/addedPicture.png
```

Im using a loop in my bash script (see below). What i need to do is, when i loop through my root directory of the files/folders that have been either added, or deleted, I need to

A. print out "Deleting" [X] or "Adding" [X]

B. Determine based on the first char (?,!) if I should delete or add the current file in the loop to svn.

Im just not sure the syntax of how to parse the string "!       /myLocalDir/files/deletedPicture.png" to do that

```
for X in `svn status /myLocalDir/files | cut -c 8-300`
            do  
                if [ "!" ]
                    then
                        echo "Deleting " $X
                        #svn $CREDENTIALS delete $X
                    else
                        echo "Adding " $X
                        #svn $CREDENTIALS  add $X
                fi

            done
```

one other thing i am noticing.. even thought svn status in the command line

```
!        /myLocalDir/files/deletedPicture.png
?        /myLocalDir/files/addedPicture.png
```

my bash loop echo's like this

```
!        
/myLocalDir/files/deletedPicture.png
?
/myLocalDir/files/addedPicture.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the input!! but this is what i went with.. all i really needed to do was determine base on the first char of a string which was delete and which was add so I substring'd it. I replaced the spaces with dashes which solved my for looping issue and then I substring each one for my condition

```
for X in `svn status /myLocalDir/files |tr " " "-"`
            do  
                if [ ${X:0:1} == "!" ]
                    then
                        echo "Deleting " ${X:8}
                        svn delete ${X:8}
                    elif [ ${X:0:1} == "?" ]
                        echo "Adding " ${X:8}
                        svn add ${X:8}
                fi

            done
```

Comment: this is from svn help status   '?' item is not under version control
      '!' item is missing (removed by non-svn command) or incomplete

Answer (score 3):

`X` is only going to be a single field, not an entire line, the way your code is written. Try this:

```
while IFS= read -r status file; do
    case $status in
      \! )  echo "Deleting" ;;
      \? ) echo "Adding" ;;
      # etc.
    esac
done <( svn status /myLocalDir/files )
```

You can vary the patterns to match whatever status code `svn status` returns, and put whatever code you need in place of the `echo`s in this skeleton.

Edit: adding Josh's code to the answer to provide better formatting:

```
while read -r line; do
    file="${line#????????}"        # Strip off the 7 flag columns and the separator
    status="${line%$file}"         # Get the 7 flags columns
    case "$status" in 
        '!'*) echo "Do something" ;;
        '?'*) echo "Do something else with $file";;
    esac
 done <( svn status /myLocalDir/files )
```

Comment: If there is ever any _additional_ flags present, this will break.  One way you might fix it is to change the conditionals a bit and use a parameter expansion: `while IFS= read -r line; do file="${line#????????}"; status="${line%$file}"; case "$status" in '!'*) echo "Do something with $file";; '?'*) echo "Do something else with $file";; esac; done`

Comment: Good point. I haven't used `svn` in a while and forgot exactly what the `status` command could return.

Comment: You'll need to fix your edit to include unsetting IFS for the read call, otherwise leading whitespace will be removed (which is bad, because then that'll break the Parameter Expansion to remove the columns).

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to check is the first word and consider the rest as 2nd word then you can do:

```
svn status /myLocalDir/files | while IFS= " " read -r line;
            do  
            read a b <<<$line

                if [ $a == "!" ]
                    then
                        echo "Deleting " "$b"
                        #svn $CREDENTIALS delete $b
                    else
                        echo "Adding " "$b"
                        #svn $CREDENTIALS  add $b
                fi
            done
```

Comment: Status have more variation than two, read `svn help status`. You FAIL

Comment: I don't know how many columns it would print as mentioned before. If only the first word is needed to checked, then this will work.

Comment: Easy Lazy Badger.. his first solution was not that off base

Comment: @LazyBadger The question is also tagged in bash. OP mentioned only 2 statuses. I don't have to read what svn returns. I answered based on what's given. Besides, mind your language. It' ok to disagree. But abusing is not on.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you can do it in more easy and elegant (or maybe even correct) ways

- Adding all new files in tree in one command: `svn add --force /myLocalDir/files/*` (--force is needed because there are already versioned files, which produce otherwise *warning* "... is already under version control"), maybe it can be usable without --force, but with -q for suppressing output
- One-liners with pipes for adding|deleting without big bashisms:

`svn status | awk '/\?/ {print $2}' | xargs svn add`

`svn status | awk '/\!/ {print $2}' | xargs svn rm`

Comment: Or even `svn status | sed -ne 's/^?/svn add/p;s/^!/svn rm/p' | sh` as long as the filenames don't contain incompatible characters, like spaces.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: added all possible fields for stat. See `svn help status` for their meaning and values.

```
treeConflict=" "
oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $(svn stat "$path")
do 
   if [[ "$treeConflict" == "C" ]]; then
       continue # skip or handle tree conflict line
   fi

   operation="${line:0:1}"
   modifications="${line:1:1}"
   lock="${line:2:1}"
   history="${line:3:1}"
   external="${line:4:1}"
   repoLock="${line:5:1}"
   treeConflict="${line:6:1}"
   file="$(echo ${line} | sed "s#^.......##")"
done
IFS="$oldIFS"
```

Comment: all i care about is ? or !  added or deleted files

Comment: Then ignore the fields you don't need. You still have $operation and $file.